# how to get Facebook page data to my android application?

Tags: android, facebook

I need to get my fan page data i.e number of likes, recent liked users; to my android application.

**With out log in to facebook the application user should be abel to use the app.**

I tried [Facebook SDK for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/), but didn't find a way to access page data. It seems that a user should be logged in to facebook in order to get data.

When I check on [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), the number of likes can be accessed. But how to do this for a given page without asking the user to log in?

any idea on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you know how to achieve same using the sdk 3.0 using graph api? is please share some code

Comment: Can you please share the code, you have tried to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
With out log in to facebook the application user should be abel to use the app.
```

**Without Login to facebook you can't access Facebook Details**

Use below this Snippet to get Pages information to which user subscribed :

```
Bundle likes_params = new Bundle();
likes_params.putString("fields", "id,name,picture");
jObj_friends_likes = new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("me/likes",likes_params));
```

where authenticatedFacebook is your Facebook instance & fields you can add whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

some page info can be accessed without user login, such as number of likes; for details, you can check them out [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

and here is how you can get them:

```
private Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook("xxxxxx");
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

mAsyncRunner.request("yourPage", new RequestListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, response);   // page info JSONObject
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) { }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) { }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) { }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) { }

});
```

**P.S.** [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a great tool for playing with the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

after installing Facebook SDK, try this

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"/{page-id}",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```